# Converting String to URL return nil

Tags: swift3

```
var url:String = "http://112.199.178.73:4000/contact" + "?" + ["accessToken": getAppDelegate().applicationData?.accessToken].queryStringWithEncoding();

var socketUrl = URL(string: url);
```

Comment: Do not call `URL(string:)`. Use URLComponents.

Comment: Need to use here `var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("your access token", forHTTPHeaderField: "accessToken")`  . You can't convert `String` with `Dictionary` to `URL` thats why you getting `nil` here.

Comment: thanks @matt. It's all going well using URLComponents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't build out URLs and URL strings manually like that.

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "http"
components.host = "112.199.178.73"
components.port = 4000
components.path = "/contact"

// I'm assuming accessToken is a string here
if let accessToken = getAppDelegate().applicationData?.accessToken {
    components.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "accessToken", value: accessToken)
    ]
}

guard let url = components.url else {
    fatalError("Failed to create URL")
}
```

If you could post the string that `var url:String = "http://112.199.178.73:4000/contact" + "?" + ["accessToken": getAppDelegate().applicationData?.accessToken].queryStringWithEncoding();`
 generates we could tell you exactly what's going wrong, but I bet that however `["accessToken": getAppDelegate().applicationData?.accessToken].queryStringWithEncoding();` is getting appended to that string is going to give you an improper url string.

Comment: Thank you @andrew for your flawless answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! If this did the trick for you, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)!